# What calendar did the Mauryan Empire use?

Tags: india, calendar, ancient-india, chronology

Research has brought up conflicting answers to this question and the answers I have gotten are generally confusing and poorly written.

I'm wondering what calendar the [Mauryan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauryan_Empire) used and what year Ashoka was born in, in accordance to that calendar.

Comment: If you can indicate some of the sources you've looked at so far, that will be helpful. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka) says that Ashoka was born c. 304 BCE.

Comment: Calendars and dating systems change with time. What time period of general usage are you interested in?

Comment: @BrianZ I'm aware that Ashoka was born in 304 BCE / 304 B.C but that's via the Gregorian Calendar not whatever calendar the Mauryan Empire used.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens. I think the question is very clear. It is about the Maurya period.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm not sure if the Maruyan Empire ever changed calendars but I guess whatever Calendar was in use during Bindusara's reign.

Comment: @BrianZ. Even the Wikipedia article admits that the date of Asoka is debated. Some scholars put it as late as about 200 AD.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kandahar_Greek_Edicts_of_Ashoka#Translation shows a regnal date in one of Ashoka's edicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence for any calendar system in India at the time of Ashoka. His inscriptions do not mention any dates. Sometimes historians need to admit that they do not have the answers.

Comment: Which historians have you read that claim to have the answer? I'm not aware of any, but this is not an area where I can claim extensive knowledge.  I'm aware that some estimates have been made, based on his inscriptions (those don't include dates, but they do name several contemporaries whose dates _are_ known), however historians are generally careful to specify the limits of their knowledge.  You might find [Ashoka in Ancient India](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674057777) by Nayanjot Lahiri of interest.

Comment: @fdb Does that mean that no Indian calendar has been discovered for that period or that the Maruyan's simply lacked a calendar?

Comment: @JordanTheCynic. Presumably they had some sort of calendar, but it is not mentioned in the inscriptions of that period.

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The Mauryan empire used the **Vedic calendar(s)**, many versions of it, and later the **Greco-Indian calendar** [For more info see: Calendars in India](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-1-4020-4425-0_8485).